# Salvage HDD data from VMWare in Windows

Tags: windows-10, vmware, hypervisor

So this might be a bit of a weird one.

I had an old server running VMWare. And it died. The only other machine I have access to atm is older and I can't seem to get VMWare running on it.

So my question is, is there any way that I can salvage the data from the 2 HDD's that I was running in the VMWare machine, but through Windows?

I added them to the Windows machine and they show up in Disk Management, but not in File Explorer.

Comment: I don't have an backups, It's not critical data. Just data I would like to have.
In Disk Management, It doesn't allow me to assign a drive letter. Everything is greyed out apart from "Convert to Dynamic Disk"

Comment: I assume by “VMWare” you mean ESXi?

Comment: Does this VMware article help you?  https://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=32312.htm

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, I believe it was ESXi. It was the Free Hypervisor

Comment: @John I'm not sure tbh. I've never used that CommCell before. Would it be able to view the VHD's that are on the HDDs?

Comment: I am not sure. What I have seen for ESXi is data recovery agencies. I posted before you clarified that you were using ESXi.

Comment: @obiwanconobi - You need to tell us what you were running.  If you want to transfer the virtual machine from the HDD that’s easy enough.  However, that requires you to provide us accurate information about what you were using.  Windows won’t be able to read the file system you were using.

Comment: @Ramhound I was running ESXi version 5.5

Comment: ESXi uses a Linux kernel.  So Ubuntu would have no problem moving or copying the files to a FAT32 or NTFS volume which Windows could access

Comment: @Ramhound Ah cool, thanks for your help i'll give it ago

Comment: In case you have access to VMDK drives, you can extract the content of each drive.
https://www.vmwareblog.org/4-ways-extract-content-vmdk-vm-totally-dead/
In case you need to have VMs running on Hyper-V, you can simply convert VMDK to VHDX.